# How many times is .htaccess parsed and the RewriteRule directives run?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is a trivial question but I wanted to double check.

How many times is the following `.htaccess` run through?

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ bla [L]
RewriteRule bla foo [L]
```

The `[L]` as I understand stops executing `RewriteRule`'s for the rest of the file, but does it then start all over again?

This may seem like a dumb question, so I apologize in advance, but in my very limited experience with writing `RewriteRule`'s I've gotten the feeling that the `.htaccess` file is sometimes parsed more than once.

Comment: The L flag will tell Apache to stop processing the rewrite rules for that request. Now what is often unrealised is that it now makes a new request for the new, rewritten filename and begin processing the rewrite rules again.

Comment: I just want to comment that this is not at all a dumb question -- it is a very confusing concept and the apache docs aren't much help.

Comment: @gview, you are exactly right. I actually said it was a dumb question before I knew the answer. Now that I know the answer, I realize that it's not a trivial question. And indeed, the documentation is very much lacking on this topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the L flags do not work the way you think they do in that example.  Because the .htaccess file is in the "per directory" context, mod_rewrite creates a subrequest process.  That process will keep processing rules until it can not process anymore, or it is interrupted as in your example with L flag.

However, because a rewrite was triggered via rule #1, the rewrite engine will create a new subrequest and go through the .htaccess rules again.  It repeats this process so long as a rewrite occurs, and only passes processing on when there are no rewrites.

In your example, the L flags are not only not doing what you thing they are, they are actually making things slower by requiring apache to create multiple subrequests, rather than using a single subrequest that handles both the rules and then completes.

Comment: the processing is passed also when rewrites that don't change the URL occur (for example rewrites that change the query string)

Answer (score 0):

It's processed once for input "bla" and twice for all other inputs because a successful rewrite that changes the internal URL will cause an internal redirect after processing the whole .htaccess. Note that the second RewriteRule is never processed, probably because the first rule is always triggered.

If you want to make it loop, you could prepend the first rule with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !bla` or swap the order of the two rules. Then the .htaccess will be processed 11 times (default max 10 redirects if you didn't set a different value for `LimitInternalRecursion`) and then a 500 Internal Server Error will be issued.

You can see what it's doing by setting `LogLevel rewrite:trace2` or higher in your httpd.conf and looking at your error.log